# jQuery Fancybox options being ignored

Tags: jquery, fancybox

on the site I'm working on I have a fancybox that triggers when the page loads that displays the contents of a hidden `<div>`, but for some reason any options such as height, width etc are getting ignored. I need to be able to use the 'callbackOnShow:' option as I need to have some `click()` functions within the fancybox.

My code is as follows, and is within a document ready function:

I put the height 5000 thing in as a test, as nothing seems to be working.

```
// FANCY BOX
    if ($('#link').length) {
        $('#link').click(function(){
            $('#link').fancybox({
                'scrolling' : 'no',
                'hidth': 5000,
                'height': 465,
                'content' : $("#lightbox-content").html()
            });
        });
    }

    $("#link").fancybox().trigger('click');
```

Any idea why this would not be working as expected?

Thanks, Dave

Updated Code:

```
// FANCY BOX
$("#link").fancybox({
    'scrolling' : 'no',
    'width': 5000, 
    'height': 2000,
    'callbackOnShow': function() { alert('hello'); },
    'content' : $("#lightbox-content").html()
}).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't re-create the fancybox, so when you're calling `$("#link").fancybox()` you're creating a fancybox with default options *right then*...later specifying the options won't override the defaults you already used.

To get what you're after, just provide the options at the time you're calling it:

```
$("#link").fancybox({
  'scrolling' : 'no',
  'width': 5000, //was hidth, make sure to correct this
  'height': 465,
  'content' : $("#lightbox-content").html()
}).trigger('click');
```

Also in jQuery there's no need for a `.length` check, if it finds elements it'll do something, if it doesn't then it won't...it's handled internally as part of how jQuery chaining works.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've just tried doing as you said but it still doesn't seem to be working. I've updated my original post with my current code.

Comment: @Probocop - What's `callbackOnShow`? Did you mean `onStart` or `onComplete`?  Or just binding a separate `click` event?

Comment: @Nick Craver - Apparently I'd need to put any functions I want to use inside the fancybox within a callbackOnShow option

Comment: @Probocop - I think you want `onComplete` then, it fires after the content is loaded.